# Using pytest coverage, is there a way to tell which tests invoked a particular statement?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I am looking at an html coverage report generated by pytest-cov and I wonder if I can find which tests have invoked a particular line (which test covered a particular line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coverage.py includes a feature called "contexts" which can easily be used to annotate results with test names: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html

Put this in your .coveragerc file:

```
[run]
dynamic_context = test_function
```

Comment: I used `--cov-context=test` option for pytest and I had to add `[html]
show_contexts = True` to the .coveragerc to see the contexts in the html.